# Adding column dynamically on rowdatabound event in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a dynamic column in grid view on rowdatabound event. The column I have added is showing in the gridview, but when I try to export gridview data, the gridview columns in code behind doesn't show this column "Test". The rest of the data is exported successfully. In the html markup I can see that other header columns are having property named scope="col". How can I set this property, so that this dynamically added column "Test" comes with gridview columns and I can export all the data including "Test" column data.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {                
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = "Test";
                e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                TableHeaderCell hcell = new TableHeaderCell();                
                hcell.Text = "Test";
                e.Row.Cells.Add(hcell);
            }
        }
```